# In AspNet.Core the Tag Helper asp-area doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-areas, tag-helpers

I recently updated the **Visual Studio** for `Update 3` and **ASP.Net Core** for 1.0.0.

I followed the tutorial in [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/1.0.0/tutorials/first-mvc-app/index.html) and I tried set up for use Areas like this https://docs.asp.net/en/1.0.0/mvc/controllers/areas.html

However, the link generated was http://localhost:2187/?area=Admin, instead of http://localhost:2187/Admin/Home/Index

**Update**

My routes:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "areaRoute",
                    template: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
            });
```

What is wrong?

**Solution**

The problem was in the order of the routes as answer mentioned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This indicates that you do not have a route registered where it takes in an area.

An example of an route for areas:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
  routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute",
    template: "{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

  routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
      template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});
```

**Update**:

You must reorder the routes as in this case the first route would be matched. I would suggest to take a look at the [routing docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html) to know why the order is important.

Comment: It's looke like [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/1.0.0/mvc/controllers/areas.html)