# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Areas routing not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have this folder structure for my new Area

[image]

This is how I set it up in my startup:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "areas",
      template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

This is how I created my basecontroller

```
namespace App.Areas.Applications.Controllers
{
    [Area("Applications")]
    [Authorize]
    public abstract class ApplicationsBaseController : Controller
    {

    }
}
```

My ApplicationsController then inherits the BaseController

However, when I set a link like this

```
<li class="nav-item"><a asp-area="Applications" asp-controller="Applications" asp-action="Index" class="nav-link">Applications</a></li>
```

This is the link that shows up in my url https://localhost:44338/Applications?area=Applications and I get a page cannot be found.

What did I miss when setting up my Area?

EDIT:

When I add [Route("Applications/[controller]")] after my [Area("Applications")], I get this error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following
>   actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> App.Areas.Applications.Controllers.ApplicationsController.Index (App)
>   App.Areas.Applications.Controllers.ApplicationsController.Create (App)
>   App.Areas.Applications.Controllers.ApplicationsController.NewRole
>   (App)

Comment: have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36535512/7124761

Comment: Yeah thats what I followed

Comment: I have also added more information to my question

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38253273/7124761 one also

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Same errors appearing

Comment: As I checked your error its clearly says that the action name is an Ambiguous, Post your all action methods in the question or check for the same

Comment: I think I found out why but I'm not sure I know how to solve it. This expects my Views to be in a Views/Applications folder. But my views are located in just Views. How can I change that?

Comment: This will help -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/40795673/7124761

Comment: This expects my Views to be in a Views/Applications folder. But my views are located in just Views. How can I change that?--- > `Create new folder under Views folder callled Application and move application controller views into this`

Comment: No I mean I want my views to just be left in Views and not me needing to create a folder because then the structure doesnt make sense? Applications/Views/Applications/Index.cshtml

Answer (score 12):

Put it before the default route... like this

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
 routes.MapRoute(
  name: "areas",
  template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: This is such an obscure information. This deserves more votes.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should create `Controller` folder to the specific views. Otherwise, it will fail when there are multiple controllers in the `Applications` area.

Anyway, for returning the views just in `Views Folder`, try to configure the `AreaViewLocationFormats` to specify the views search location.

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //rest services
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1).AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
        {
            o.AreaViewLocationFormats.Add("/Areas/{2}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized what the issue was. In each controller, I needed to declare [Area="AreaName"] in the top before anything else so that the routing worked.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option which does bring some clarification in terms of meta data of the code:

Using MapAreaRoute extension method in
Namespace: **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder**

Here is an example:

```
          routes.MapAreaRoute(
                name: "AdminArea",
                areaName: "Admin",
                template: Admin/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

It is available from .NET Core 1.0

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.mvcarearoutebuilderextensions.maparearoute?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Answer (score 0):

**you can use simple solation**

**Extension**

```
public static class AreaExtension
{
    public static string AreaUrl(this IHtmlHelper helper, string action,  params string[] parameters)
    {
        var viewContext = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;

        string controller = (string)viewContext["controller"],
         area = (string)viewContext["area"];
        return GenerateUrl(action, controller, area, parameters);
    }

    public static string AreaUrl(this IHtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller, params string[] parameters)
    {
        var viewContext = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;

        string area = (string)viewContext["area"];
        return GenerateUrl(action, controller, area, parameters);
    }

    public static string AreaUrl(this IHtmlHelper helper, string action, string controller, string area, params string[] parameters)
        => GenerateUrl(action, controller, area, parameters);

    private static string GenerateUrl(string action, string controller, string area, params string[] parameters)
    {
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(controller));
        if (controller == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));

        string urlParams = string.Empty;

        if (parameters != null && parameters.Length > 0)
            urlParams = "?" + string.Join("&", parameters);

        return "/" + string.Join("/", area, controller, action) + urlParams;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

Incluse **namespase** `AreaExtension` in `_ViewImports.cshtml`

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="@Html.AreaUrl("Index", "Applications","Applications")" class="nav-link">Applications</a></li>
```

> This AreaExtension have 3 overload